# Trello API: getting boards / lists / cards information

Tags: list, trello

Using Trello API:

- I've been able to get all the cards that are assigned to a Trello user
- I've been able to get all the boards that are assigned to an Organization

But I can't get any API call that returns all the lists that are in an Organization or User.
Is there any function that allows that ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't believe there is a method in the [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/api/index.html) to do this, so you'll have to get a list of boards for a user or organization:

[GET /1/members/[idMember or username]/boards](https://trello.com/docs/api/member/index.html#get-1-members-idmember-or-username-boards)

Which returns (truncated to show just the parts we care about):

```
[{
    "id": "4eea4ffc91e31d1746000046",
    "name": "Example Board",
    "desc": "This board is used in the API examples",
    ...
    "shortUrl": "https://trello.com/b/OXiBYZoj"
}, {
    "id": "4ee7e707e582acdec800051a",
    "name": "Public Board",
    "desc": "A board that everyone can see",
    ...
    "shortUrl": "https://trello.com/b/IwLRbh3F"
}]
```

Then get the lists for each board:

[GET /1/boards/[board_id]/lists](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-lists)

Which returns (truncated to only show the list id and name:

```
[{
    "id": "4eea4ffc91e31d174600004a",
    "name": "To Do Soon",
    ...
}, {
    "id": "4eea4ffc91e31d174600004b",
    "name": "Doing",
    ...
}, {
    "id": "4eea4ffc91e31d174600004c",
    "name": "Done",
    ...
}]
```

And go through this response for each board to build a list of all the lists a user or organization has.

Comment: As of now, there is a call to get a listing of all the boards on a trello organization.  /organization/ORG_ID/boards?fields=name 

You can still pass each one of the IDs to fetch the lists of the boards

Answer (score 47):

For the users who want the easiest way to access the id of a list :

**Use the ".json" hack !**

add ".json" at the end of your board URL to display the same output of the API query for that board, **in your browser** ! (no other tool needed, no hassle dealing with authentication).

For instance, if the URL of your board is :

```
https://trello.com/b/EI6aGV1d/blahblah
```

point your browser to

```
https://trello.com/b/EI6aGV1d/blahblah.json
```

And you will obtain something like

```
{
  "id": "5a69a1935e732f529ef0ad8e",
  "name": "blahblah",
  "desc": "",
  "descData": null,
  "closed": false,
  [...]
    "cards": [
      {
          "id": "5b2776eba95348dd45f6b745",
          "idMemberCreator": "58ef2cd98728a111e6fbd8d3",
          "data": {
            "list": {
              "name": "Bla blah blah blah blah",
              "id": "5a69a1b82f62a7af027d0378"
            },
            "board": {
            [...]
```

Where you can just search for the name of your list to easily find its id next to it.

tip: use a json viewer extension to make your browser display a nice json. Personnally I use https://github.com/tulios/json-viewer/tree/0.18.0 but I guess there are a lot of good alternatives out there.

[image]

Comment: And you can use the `fields` query param (`...json?fields=...`) to filter out unnecessary fields of the output

Answer (score 4):

to get all your boards use

```
Trello.get("/members/me/boards")
```

worked for me using **client.js**

Comment: This works even with the basic Trello REST API: `https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by calling

GET /1/organizations/[idOrg]/boards?lists=all

It is here: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/organization#get-1-organizations-idorg-or-name-boards

Look at the arguments.

There are several filters and fields. You can customize it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty bash script using `curl` and `jq` to get any given Board's ID or List's Id:

```sh
key="<your-key>"
token="<your-token>"
trelloUsername="<you-trello-username>"
boardName="<board-name>"
listName="<list-name>"

boardID=$(curl -s --request GET --url "https://api.trello.com/1/members/$trelloUsername/boards?key=$key&token=$token" --header 'Accept: application/json' | jq -r ".[] | select(.name == \"$boardName\").id")
echo "boardID: ${boardID}"
listID=$(curl -s --request GET --url "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/$boardID/lists?key=$key&token=$token" | jq -r ".[] | select(.name == \"$listName\").id")
echo "listID: ${listID}"
```

Example output:

```
boardID: 5eab513c719d2d681bafce0e
listID: 5eab519e66dd4272gb720e22
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all your Trello boards using the REST API via **POSTMAN (in 2023)**:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "key": "{{ KEY }}",
  "token": "{{ TOKEN }}"
}'
```

Go to: `Import > Raw Text` paste the code and execute`