# Trello API - Get only boards with cards in a specific list (In Progress, for example)

Tags: javascript, json, api, trello

Got all boards using

```
"https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/"+orgId+"/boards?key="+key+"&token="+token;
```

Got all lists using

```
"https://api.trello.com/1/boards/"+boardId+"/lists?cards=all&key="+key+"&token="+token;
```

But how to display only boards with cards in a specific list ? In progress, for example ?

**Edit:** problem solver!

I managed to get all boards and all lists with their cards, and display the boards with cards only inside 'in progress' list.

```
Trello.get('organization/'+orgId+'/boards/?token='+token+'&lists=open', function(boards) {
        $.each(boards, function(ix, board) {
            Trello.get('boards/'+board.id+'/lists?cards=all&token='+token, function(lists) {
                $.each(lists, function(lx, list) {
                if(list.name.toLowerCase()=='in progress' && list.cards.length > 0) {
                    console.log(board.name);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trello API: getting boards / lists / cards information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552278/trello-api-getting-boards-lists-cards-information)